# Mexican wave effect in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve mexican wave problem in which every other character should be capitalized and should be returned to a string.
for ex: ['hello'] should be ['Hello','hEllo','heLlo','helLo','hellO']
The code that I have written works fine but when two same letters come it capitalizes both of them at the same time.
here is my code:

```
s='hello'
new=[]
for i, val in enumerate(s[:]):
    up=s[i].upper()
    c=s.replace(s[i],up)
    new.append(c)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.replace` returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting the number of replacements to max. In your example - all lowercase occurrences of letter `l` are replaced with `L`. Instead, try string slicing, like follow:

```
s='hello'
new=[]
for i, val in enumerate(s[:]):
    up=s[i].upper()
    c=s[:i] + up + s[i+1:]
    new.append(c)
print(new)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLlo', 'helLo', 'hellO']
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with less lines of code:

```
s='hello'
new=[]
for i, val in enumerate(s):
    new.append("{0}{1}{2}".format(s[:i],s[i].upper(),s[i+1:]))
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with input: "two words" because of whitespaces

```
def wave(people):
    
    if len(people) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        people = people.lower()
        the_waves = []
        for e,i in enumerate(people):
            if i == " ":
                continue
            else:
                the_waves.append(people[:e] + people[e].upper() + people[e+1:])
        return the_waves
```

Answer (score 0):

Mexican Wave Golang

```
func wave(words string) []string {
  var result []string
  result = make([]string, 0, len(words))
  for i := 0; i < len(words); i++ {
    if !(unicode.IsSpace(rune(words[i]))) {
        result = append(result, words[:i]+strings.ToUpper(words[i:i+1])+words[i+1:])
    }
  }

  return result
  }
```